# Difficulty understanding virtual LPIs in GICv3

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt

The next paragraph is in the GICv3 specification:

> In GICv3 LPIs can be presented to a virtualized system by the hypervisor, which must be using the System registers. A virtual LPI is generated when the hypervisor writes a vINTID corresponding to the LPI range, that is a vINTID that is greater than 8191, to a List register. Because an LPI does not have an active state, it is not possible to associate a virtual LPI with a physical interrupt.

I'm not understanding the last sentence. Despite LPI cannot have an active state, why vLPI cannot be associated with physical LPI? And what implications do I have if a physical interrupt ID isn't associated to the virtual interrupt ID?

Thank you!